# How to display subtitle/scope (global, store view) with UI component form element heading

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

I am creating a custom module in the admin which is EAV and is supporting multi store view. I want to show the scope with the field as In attached image. How can this be accomplished using UI Component.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using **scopeLabel**

```
<item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">[Global]</item>
```

The full example is

```
<field name="store_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Number</item>
                    <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">[Global]</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">my-custom-class</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```